# Switch console output to RS232

Tags: linux, console, redirection, serial

How can I switch temporally Linux ASCII console to RS232 port build-in computer. I mean about Linux system working as server, without running any graphical tools on it (X11, bootsplash etc).
But I want to do it temporally just "on demand". In ordinary usage, the console should be normal VGA monitor. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you really mean "the console" or are you simply trying to attach a terminal via a serial port? In Unix, the console is one of many ttys, but it hapens to be the one where the pre-boot/boot functionality is configured via, and where some messages are written. Do you need the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Yes.

Temporarily? Too much of a hassle.

It's all well [documented in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial-console.txt), and in modern distributions it should be sufficient to edit `/etc/inittab` in order to have a terminal listening on your serial port - which is what I assume you want to do.

If you just want the console messages displayed, edit your boot options accordingy.

Comment: OK. I place something like `0:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L ttyS0 -H MEDIA 9600 vt100` but the problem is that /etc/inittab is no longer valid because systemctl is used. So what and where I have to place?

Comment: This would be a different question, and could be solved with minimal research effort, but here goes: http://bit.ly/13Uz2zi